# Meteor: trying to add another field to the user profile Accounts.onCreateUser();

Tags: javascript, meteor

Basically trying to modify the user that was just created by giving it an extra field called `sid` in it's profile object. I'm running this on server.js (the server code)

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {      
        Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set: {"user.profile.sid": [post.content]}});
});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
```

However, the user object does not show the `sid` field in it's output. Am I doing  this in the wrong location or is my code wrong?

Comment: Is this a field that you want your users to be able to change to anything they want?  If not, move it out of user.profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)

> The function you pass will be called with two arguments: options and user. The options argument comes from Accounts.createUser for password-based users or from an external service login flow. options may come from an untrusted client so make sure to validate any values you read from it. The user argument is created on the server and contains a proposed user object with all the automatically generated fields required for the user to log in, including the _id.
>
> The function should return the user document (either the one passed in or a newly-created object) with whatever modifications are desired. The returned document is inserted directly into the Meteor.users collection.

So your code should be:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {      
    user.profile.sid = [post.content];
    return user;
});
```

[However be aware that anything in the user.profile object can be changed by your users](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users).

> profile: an Object which the user can create and update with any data. Do not store anything on profile that you wouldn't want the user to edit unless you have a deny rule on the Meteor.users collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {      
    user.profile.sid = [post.content];
    return user;
});
```

From the documentation it reads (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser):

> The user argument is created on the server and contains a proposed user object...

So at this point it looks like the user does not actually exist in the database yet.